# include_once, relative path in php

Tags: php, file, include-path

I have 3 files: home, failed_attempt, login.

The file home and failed_attempt all refer to login file.

The annoying thing is that they throw a mistake saying that the login file doesnt exist. home will throw an exception if i do this, but failed_attempt wont.

```
  include_once("../StoredProcedure/connect.php");
```

include_once("../untitled/sanitize_string.php");

and if I do this:

```
   include_once("StoredProcedure/connect.php");
   include_once("untitled/sanitize_string.php");
```

the opposite happens, failed_attempt throws an exception , but home, wont. How do I fix this..

Do I tell the include to go up a page by putting this ../ , and therefore home.php doesnt need to go one page up therefore it throws that exception..

How can I make it so both files accept those inclueds as valid.. perhaps not relative to where they are placed.. i.e. without that ../

Directory structure:

```
PoliticalForum
->home.php
->StoredProcedure/connect.php
->untitled/sanitize_string.php
->And other irrelevant files
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Are the home, failed_attempt and login files in the same directory?  Can you post your directory structure?  How exactly do the home and failed_attempt pages "refer" to the login file?  In which file does the above code appear?

Comment: storedProcedure is my folder and it has files inside. everything as outlined.. login file has got 2 includes in it which fail to load, depending on where you call them from...homepage or login_attempt page which is inside a different directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are three possible solutions.  The second are really just work-arounds that use absolute paths in a clever way.

**1: chdir into the correct directory**

```
<?php

// check if the 'StoredProcedure' folder exists in the current directory
// while it doesn't exist in the current directory, move current 
// directory up one level.
//
// This while loop will keep moving up the directory tree until the
// current directory contains the 'StoredProcedure' folder.
//
while (! file_exists('StoredProcedure') )
    chdir('..');

include_once "StoredProcedure/connect.php";
// ...
?>
```

Note that this will only work if your StoredProcedure folder is in the topmost directory of any files that might need to include the files it contains.

**2: Use absolute paths**

Now before you say this is not portable, it actually depends on how you implement it.  Here's an example that works with Apache:

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/StoredProcedure/connect.php";
// ...
?>
```

Alternatively, again with apache, put the following in your .htaccess in the root directory:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/example.php
```

Then in example.php:

```
<?php

define('MY_DOC_ROOT', '/path/to/docroot');

?>
```

And finally in your files:

```
<?php
include_once MY_DOC_ROOT . "/StoredProcedure/connect.php";
// ...
?>
```

**3: Set PHP's include_path**

See [the manual entry for the include_path directive](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).  If you don't have access to php.ini, then this can be set in .htaccess, providing you are using Apache and PHP is *not* installed as CGI, like so:

```
php_value include_path '/path/to/my/includes/folder:/path/to/another/includes/folder'
```

Comment: I am a bit obscure about how the first method works. But I will try the second and third methods

Comment: I've added comments to the first method.  For more info, see [the chdir manual page](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php).

Answer (score 11):

Things like `realpath()` and `__DIR__` are your friends when it comes to creating paths in PHP.

**Realpath** http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

**Magic constants** http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Since include and require are language constructs (rather than functions) they don't need brackets. Generally speaking you'd use `include` to include "templates" (output files) and `require` to include PHP files such as classes.

So you could use something like:

```
$sPath = realpath( __DIR__ . '/../relative/path/here');
if($sPath) { require_once $sPath; }
```

(use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__` on PHP < 5)

It's worth evaluating the path before attempting to require the file as `realpath()` returns false if the file doesn't exist and attempting to `require false;` spaffs out a PHP error.

Alternatively you can just use absolute paths like:

`require /home/www/mysite.com/htdocs/inc/somefile.php`

Comment: That doesnt work too :    include_once(realpath("../untitled/sanitize_string.php"));

Comment: It did remove the errors. But what if realpath returns false? wouldnt it mean the file wont be included.. when does realpath returns false??

Comment: `realpath()` returns false if the path entered as the parameter doesn't exist, for example `realpath('this/file/does/not/exist');` would return false - if the file **does** exist then it'll return the real path to the given file so `realpath(__DIR__ . '/this/file/does/exist');` might return something like `/home/mysite.com/htdocs/this/file/does/exist` - e.g. the full actual path.

Comment: I used tried and catch in __autoload function..I had no choice ..no idea of how to overcome that conflict. Why an absolute path wouldnt work...like this PoliticalForum/untitled.. why cant that path work for all files no matter what they are..I hate relative path

Comment: One other way around it might be to put all your includes in a single folder and set that as the "include path" using something like `set_include_path()` (there are other ways though) ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: hmm..sounds interesting. wont it be a bit cumbersome on the system include all those files again and again each time I refer to that file? But still it creates a problem..cause if I put files inside files , it means I have to do this ../../relativepath.php , whereas, for other files I will need to do this ../relativepath.php and for the files in the main directory or same directory as I call the include from , I need to do this relativepath.php. So that relative path is a garbage invention. is there an alternative to it?

Answer (score 6):

For the beginners this will help to understand. Use simply the following based on your relative path:

```
//include file directly from parent directory:
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../connect.php');
```

OR

```
//include file from parent's child directory:
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../StoredProcedure/connect.php');
```

OR

```
//include file from own child directory:
include_once('StoredProcedure/connect.php');
```

OR

```
//include sibling files from same directory:
include_once('connect.php');
```

Comment: my case is the second scenario, this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like `require(dirname(__FILE__) . '[RELATIVE PATH HERE]');`

Comment: do you mean something like this:    [code]include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "../StoredProcedure/connect.php");
   include_once(dirname(__FILE__) ."../untitled/sanitize_string.php");
   .. it doesnt work[/code]

Comment: dirname(__FILE__) will return current directory in which file having include code exists, just append relative path to this file. For ease you can print value of dirname(__FILE__) and see what 's happening.

Comment: but it doesnt work quite right     include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."../StoredProcedure/User/login.php"); when I include login it makes problems ...your line of code doesnt work

Comment: See comment by 'daiscog' under question and write directory structure in question.

Comment: updated. Should the _DIR_ give me the directory I am at.. so if I am at "untitled" directory in my website and home.php is in the main directory.. how does it help if I put the directory name before the relative path?

Answer (score 1):

The other guys have answered your question correctly, however I thought I'd contribute something else: autoloaders.

Autoloaders allow you to define a function that will automatically include certain files, when you attempt to use a class.

The documentation is here and can explain it better than I can: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Would really recommend using them, will save you time and is better practice.

Comment: I know about them..as you start the page the files are loaded..you put your includes inside them..but it doesnt solve the problem to my quesiton does it?