# Fatal error on require once()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build myself a website using PHP and MySQL. I get the below error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/konjam
>       /public_html/demo/cp/db.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
>       /lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/KD/demo/cat_details.php 
>       on line 5

Here's my code for the line where it says this specific error:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once("conf.php");
require_once("db.php");
$db = new db();
?>
```

Any help guys?

Comment: Is the file in the same directory as this script?

Comment: Are you sure the `db.conf` file is within same location as file script?

Comment: use absolute paths for require include etc or take sure, that include_path is in your sens

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835948/include-once-relative-path-in-php/7836018#7836018 for a similar question, complete with answers.

Comment: Yes. The file is in the same directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal Error Failed opening required File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364233/php-fatal-error-failed-opening-required-file)

Comment: @donald123: So I should replay require_once with include_path?

Comment: I tried require_once(CP.'db.php'); and it still didn't work. I put the db.php file in a folder called cp.

Comment: `require_once realpath( __DIR__ . '/cp/db.php' );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it'll surprise you but there is no `/home/konjam/public_html/demo/cp/db.php` file and `PHP` can't include it in your code.

Make sure you specify correct path to that file (maybe use `dirname(__FILE__)` and relative path?) and that `PHP` have rights to read it.

Comment: `__DIR__` works as well as `dirname(__FILE__)` unless you're on a really old version of PHP

Comment: @CD001: yep, I really don't know why I'm still using `dirname(__FILE__)`.. ;)

Comment: @ElonThan  
I tried require_once(CP.'db.php'); and it still didn't work. I put the db.php file in a folder called cp.

Answer (score 0):

the application is taken from a linux machine and put on a windows machine, in XAMPP.
you have to search for all "/home/konjam/public_html" strings in your project folder in xampp and modify the references properly, from linux to windows. It would be best to work with relative paths.

Comment: Just changing the PHP include_path setting would *probably* sort it in this instance.