# php : function require_once() path does not work

Tags: php, require

Hi I don't know which path should put into parameter in require_once()

I am working with 7.2.10-0.

I have a directory which is

```
ice_hockey > data > teams.php 
ice_hockey > view > top.php
ice_hockey > index.php
```

My teams.php is like this

```
<?php
require_once('../view/top.php');
?>
```

but It does not work.
I was searching for the path, especially relative path to put as parameter in require_once. Whatever I did, it doesn't work..

If I am put teams.php in the ice_hockey folder. 
It will be easy but I need that folder to make easy.

How can I do? What is my problem here?

Comment: Please be specific about exactly what isn't working. What are you seeing, what were you expecting? Errors? Logs? etc.

Comment: Using relative paths in PHP is generally a bad idea. https://gist.github.com/DaveRandom/6830e379578a66e2c82593137e79d099

Comment: Use a directive that will take you to the root folder(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [include\_once, relative path in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835948/include-once-relative-path-in-php)

Comment: @Tiffany Thanks!

Comment: @JonStirling I think directory that I put as a parameter is correct but, it makes error. I want to know why it doesnot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current working directory is not guaranteed to be where the script is located.  When you access index.php from the web server, your CWD is going to be ice_hockey, not ice_hockey/data.

The same would apply if you were running in the command line from the root directory and ran:

```
php ice_hockey/data/teams.php
```

The CWD would be the root directory, or where you executed the command from.

Use the magic constant `__DIR__` to use the current script's directory.

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../view/top.php');
```

This will always point to the correct location relative to where teams.php is located.